# База Данных Denwer в интернете

Tags: база-данных, denwer

Всем привет, скажите я написал программу которая использует БД, но покупать хостинг только ради БД не охота + не у всех есть удалённый доступ. Так вот скажите, можно сделать так чтобы БД которую я создал на денвере, была доступна и другим, т.е программа будет использовать базу у меня на компьютере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не буду Вам говорить насколько это неразумно и глупо и вообще, но вот по [этой](http://www.denwer.ru/faq/shared.html) ссылке написано как сделать сервер видимый из интернета. База данных соответственно будет видна тоже.